# AG data grid. how to get info on column I clicked

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, datagrid, next.js13

using AG dataGrid I want to call api everytime i click on column. Just as I was sorting but i need to call API for each sorting change. I dont know how to get information on which column I have clicked.
I have tried few ideas but dead stuck atm. I am using Typscript react NextJS13

```
  const onSortChanged = useCallback((event: any) => {
    const api = event;
    console.log(api);
  }, []);
```

on column headear click i want call api and need info what column header was clicked

```
  const onSortChanged = useCallback((event: any) => {
    const api = event.api;
    const sortState = api.getSortModel();
    if (sortState && sortState.length > 0) {
      // Assuming you only have one sorted column at a time
      const sortedColumn = sortState[0];
      console.log("Sorted Column Info:", sortedColumn);
    }
  }, []);
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.